# Using SCP command to download files from Linux server to client server

Tags: linux, shell, download, scripting, scp

I'm creating files on a Linux server that I'm logged into and I'm adding the ability for the user to download these files from the Linux server on to the connecting computer. I'm writing a scrip and using the scp command to download these files:

```
scp data.txt user@usraddress:/home/usr
```

However, I don't want to specify "user@usraddress:/home/usr" to be just my computer. I want whoever is logged onto the linux server to be able do download these files. Is there a way to get the address of the connecting computer?
How would I do this?

Forgive me if this seems elementary, I'm very new to scripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open a remote session in a GNU/Linux machine, the ssh server sets the environment variable `SSH_CONNECTION` with some connection information. You can use this variable and the `$USER` variable to fill that parameters:

```
scp data.txt $USER@${SSH_CONNECTION%% *}:/home/$USER
```

Note that as far as I know you couldn't assume the client home directory is at `/home`. As said by [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner), you could omit the destination directory to use the default location, the home directory.

```
scp data.txt $USER@${SSH_CONNECTION%% *}:
```

Comment: Just use `$USER@${SSH_CONNECTION%% *}:` as the destination. The default directory is the user's home directory. You are correct that you can't assume `/home/$USER`; Mac OS X, for example, uses `/Users/$USER` by default.